# How to get all the values of xml elements into a single dictionary using python?

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file that looks like this:[Here is the Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FMknj.png)

What I want is to get all the values inside both parent tags and sub-tags into a single python dictionary.

for example the code below gave me the output of all of the existed tags in the XML file just in single dictinary:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()
tags = [elem.tag for elem in root.iter()]
print(tags)
```

my question is that if I can get all the elemnt also in a single dictionary?
Please Help me!

Comment: instead of posting a screenshot of your data post it here..

Comment: You need `tag` names as keys and `text` as values?

Answer (score 0):

There's an easy way to do i.e use a module called [`xmltodict`](https://pypi.org/project/xmltodict/) which will return an `Ordered dict` .

```
import xmltodict
sample_xml ="""<?xml version="1.0"?>
<data>
    <country name="Liechtenstein">
        <rank>1</rank>
        <year>2008</year>
        <gdppc>141100</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
        <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
    </country>
    <country name="Singapore">
        <rank>4</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>59900</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
    </country>

    <country name="Panama">
        <rank>68</rank>
        <year>2011</year>
        <gdppc>13600</gdppc>
        <neighbor name="Costa Rica" direction="W"/>
        <neighbor name="Colombia" direction="E"/>
    </country>
</data> """

print (xmltodict.parse(sample_xml)['data'])
```

Output:

```
OrderedDict([('country', [OrderedDict([('@name', 'Liechtenstein'), ('rank', '1'), ('year', '2008'), ('gdppc', '141100'), ('neighbor', [OrderedDict([('@name', 'Austria'), ('@direction', 'E')]), OrderedDict([('@name', 'Switzerland'), ('@direction', 'W')])])]), OrderedDict([('@name', 'Singapore'), ('rank', '4'), ('year', '2011'), ('gdppc', '59900'), ('neighbor', OrderedDict([('@name', 'Malaysia'), ('@direction', 'N')]))]), OrderedDict([('@name', 'Panama'), ('rank', '68'), ('year', '2011'), ('gdppc', '13600'), ('neighbor', [OrderedDict([('@name', 'Costa Rica'), ('@direction', 'W')]), OrderedDict([('@name', 'Colombia'), ('@direction', 'E')])])])])])
```